# How to add a table row dynamically to a table layout in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, tablelayout

I am trying to add a row to a table layout, dynamically. However when I'm trying to using the code below the new table rows aren't showing up, although the code is running without crashing.

this is the code:

```
            tl1 = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tl1);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent, (float)1.0);
            layoutParams.SetMargins(10, 0, 5, 0);
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            dbname = "eventsss";
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), dbname);
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            db.CreateTable<CalendarEvent>();
            eventList = GetAllEvents();
            for (int i = 1; i <= eventList.Count; i++)
            {
                date = new TextView(this);
                date.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                date.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
                date.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
                date.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
                date.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                name = new TextView(this);
                name.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                name.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
                name.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
                name.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
                name.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tr = new TableRow(this);
                tr.LayoutParameters=layoutParams2;
                name.Text = eventList[i-1].title;
                date.Text = eventList[i-1].date;
                tr.AddView(date);
                tr.AddView(name);
                tl1.AddView(tr, i);
            }
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TableRow` should use `TableLayout.LayoutParams`.

Views inside the `TableRow` should use `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

In your code, it should be something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {

        TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        TextView date = new TextView(this);

        //Use TableRow
        date.LayoutParameters = layoutParams2;

        date.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
        date.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
        date.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
        date.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        TextView name = new TextView(this);

        //Use TableRow
        name.LayoutParameters = layoutParams2;

        name.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFFFC0"));
        name.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
        name.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Px, (float)30.0);
        name.SetPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        //Use TableLayout
        tr.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

        name.Text = "title";
        date.Text = "date";
        tr.AddView(date);
        tr.AddView(name);
        tl1.AddView(tr, i);
    }
```